# How to assign unique IntVar-s to a large set of CheckButtons in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a large set of Checkbuttons , each need a unique IntVar.
When I excecute the code to print the values of IntVar when the checkbutton is clicked , every of them except the last one prints 0 , instead of 1 .
Can anyone help me please to find out where is the problem in this code ?

```
import tkinter as tk

class application():

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        a=[]
        b=[]
        c=[1 for i in range(7)]
        k=1
        for index, item in enumerate(c):
            var=tk.IntVar()
            a.append(var)
            check=tk.Checkbutton(self.win, text='Button %d' %(k), command=  lambda: self.a(var.get()), variable =var)
            b.append(check)
            b[index].grid(row=k)
            k=k+1

    def a(self, var):
        print(var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = application()
    app.win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more minimal example - not using Tkinter - of your problem is:

```
>>> var = 'foo'
>>> command_late = lambda: var
>>> command_early = lambda v=var: v

>>> command_late(), command_early()
('foo', 'foo')

>>> var = 'bar'
>>> command_late(), command_early()
('bar', 'foo')
```

the 'bar' will be a little surprising if you expect the lambda to look up var's value right when it's defined. `command_early` does this, `command_late` doesn't.

In your code, using

```
command = lambda v=var: self.a(v.get())
```

or even

```
command = lambda var=var: self.a(var.get())
```

will refer to var right when the lambda is defined, and store its value as default argument.

Comment: I changed the command part as you said, but the result is the same . It still prints 0, for every button except the last .. :s

Comment: @E.Zag Oh! Works for me. [Here's what happens](https://gist.github.com/72541c4ec173c64ac7c4b498e42ebc16)

Comment: Awesome ... Thank you soo much !    I used var.get() instead of v.get(). Now i understand the functionality of the lambda function. Thank you again :)